# Expresso Store No tax option

Tags: expresso-store

I am new to V2 of Store and wondering how to make a product tax free?  I understand you may have to use categories not but I do not see anything in the docs or in the tax settings that shows how this is done.  Any help?

Comment: Hi Peter, what was your fix for this we have a similar conundrum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create or edit a tax rate in the **Store → Settings** area, there is a **Match Categories** field.

So you either select all of your categories, minus the *Tax-free* category you've created; or, you create a single *Taxable* category, and use that as the way to assign tax to each product (the latter is amore flexible and future-proof option).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  So best to add a new category called Taxable, and apply it to all my tax rates and then apply this Taxable category to ALL products that should be taxable.  Is there a way to have this Taxable category selected by default.  99/100 products are taxable so would love to avoid this requirement when added 99% of the products.

Comment: Correct - though no, I don't know of a way to have any categories selected by default when creating new entries.

Comment: RE Store → Settings area, *Match Categories* - should this override country specific tax rates?

Comment: I believe the conditions selected for each tax rate are AND conditions, so no.